# Difference between FOR UPDATE and START TRANSACTION in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, transactions, sql-update, innodb

I need to read a row from an innoDB-table, do some calculations in my code and then (perhaps) update the row. I need to make access to the row exclusive, meaning if 2 processes are accessing the same row at the same time, one process should wait reading the row until the other has finished updating it.

I found 2 possible solutions:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE myid=1234 FOR UPDATE;
[CalculateCalculateCalculate]
UPDATE table SET ... WHERE myid=1234;
```

or

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE myid=1234;
[CalculateCalculateCalculate]
UPDATE table SET ... WHERE myid=1234;
COMMIT;
```

I'm not sure which one to prefer. It seems, both are doing the same thing, is this true? Might one solution be faster than the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both solutions are wrong.

First, because you don't open a transaction, the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries are two separate transactions.

Second, because the `SELECT` doesn't acquire the exclusive lock you're looking for.

It has to be

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE myid=1234 FOR UPDATE;
[CalculateCalculateCalculate]
UPDATE table SET ... WHERE myid=1234;
COMMIT;
```